70s motorcycle movie with cemetery fight at the end
This is a US movie from the 1970s featuring the exploits of a motorcycle gang, I believe in California. At one point, in a small town, they come across a group of Mexicans working on their own motorcycles in their shop. The gang sneaks in and attacks them, leaving when the police arrive. One of the members steals a police motorcycle and is subsequently killed on the highway.
The gang wants to bury their fellow member in his home town. There, they destroy the church in which the service is held and then hold a long funeral march to the cemetery. The locals follow them and, at the conclusion of the film, a fight breaks out in the cemetery.
I don't recall any of the actors or the exact year. I believe the film is in color.

This is pretty much the plot of Roger Corman's The Wild Angels from 1966. From IMDb:

The biker leader Heavenly Blues (Peter Fonda) thinks he knows where his biker pal Loser's stolen bike is located. The gang goes out to vandalize the place [run by a group of Mexicans] where they suspect the bike is being kept. Two motorcycle cops shows up to check on the suspicious activity. They see the cops approaching, and flees including Loser who steal one of the police officer's bike. The other officer pursues him, and when he catches up, shoots him in the back. [...] Loser is critically wounded and dies at home of a biker friend. The gang decides to drop the body at mortuary, and later takes Loser's corps to a church for wild funeral party, where they end up beating up the pastor. By now the police is on to them, and as they go to the cemetery to bury Loser's body, they hear the cop's siren approaching.

The film stars Bruce Dern, Nancy Sinatra, Diane Ladd and Peter Fonda 3 years prior to Easy Rider, and allegedly kicked off the genre of 70s biker films. Here's the trailer:




Yes, that is absolutely it. Thank you!
